# How to create an Index on a boolean column

Tags: postgresql

My DB table has one primary key and a number of integer columns and one boolean column called paused which is not in the primary key.  This table will only ever hold a few hundred rows but I need to query the boolean column very regularly.  I need to know if any row in the boolean paused column is true, if one row is true I will return true if all are false I will return false.

Should I create an index on the boolean column and what would that syntax look like or is there any other way to optimize that query?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pause_metrics (
    consumer TEXT NOT NULL,
    timstamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    idle_counter INTEGER NOT NULL,
    paused BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(consumer)
);
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including the existing indexes) and, the query you are trying to optimize. [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: For "just a few hundred rows" and index might likely never be used to begin with - especially if the true/false values have an even distribution. If there are a lot of rows with one of the values (e.g. most of them have `paused = false`), then a filtered index might make sense e.g. `create index on the_table (some_column) where not paused`

Comment: I added the CREATE TABLE statement.  I am really interested in the quickest way of calling a query like this.     SELECT paused from purge_consumer_metrics where paused = true limit 1;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To support the following query:

```
SELECT paused 
from pause_metrics
where paused  
limit 1;
```

A filtered index would be the most efficient thing:

```
create index idx_paused on pause_metrics(paused)
where paused;
```

The actual column *in* the index doesn't really matter, the important part is the `where paused` which only indexes the rows that have `paused = true`.

To find out if all rows have `paused = false`, you can use an exists query:

```
select not exists (SELECT 1 from pause_metrics where paused limit 1) as all_active
```

This will make use of the filtered query and should be quite quick.

Comment: I only need am index on the paused column.  mostly all rows will be false. is there a way to quickly select that all rows are false? Does the index still help here?

Comment: @mrmannione. if the query for `pause = true` returns no row then you know that all rows are false

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong.   1)  I don't need an Index for this ?  2)   My best query is:   SELECT paused from purge_consumer_metrics where paused = true limit 1;

Comment: The index is used for the query I have shown. If you *need* it depends on your performance requirements and your hardware. Just test the query with and without the index, e.g. using `explain (analyze, buffers)` to do the testing